# Can you tell me what's wrong?

Tags: html

I don't know why this isn't working, can you tell me what's wrong?

```js
function swapImage() {
  var imageDisplayed = document.getElementById('display-image');
  if (imageDisplayed.scr.match("images/01.png")) {
    imageDisplayed.scr = "images/02.png";
  } else {
    imageDisplayed.scr = "images/01.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img id="display-image" onclick="swapImage()" scr="images/01.png" width="180" height="180" />
</p>
<p>Click the image to change it!</p>
```

Comment: *"Can you tell me what's wrong?"* Your title for the question is wrong

Answer (score 0):

there is an typo with `src` attribute,  correct it first
 and i suggest you to use `==`

`match()` will compare regular Expression you should use `==` operator instead

```
function swapImage() {
var imageDisplayed = document.getElementById('display-image');
if (imageDisplayed.src == "images/01.png") {
imageDisplayed.src = "images/02.png";
}
else {
imageDisplayed.src = "images/01.png";
}
}
```

and as Navaneeth mohan said, you need to fix type with attribute `src` too

Answer (score 0):

I believe the there is a typo there. **src** is what you should use in order to get the source property of an html element using javascript.

```
function swapImage() {
  var imageDisplayed = document.getElementById('display-image');
  if (imageDisplayed.src == "images/01.png") {
    imageDisplayed.src = "images/02.png";
  }
  else {
    imageDisplayed.src = "images/01.png";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a typo and it should be `src`. Secondly, instead of `if-else`, you can use the ternary operator:

```
function swapImage() {
  var imageDisplayed = document.getElementById('display-image');
  imageDisplayed.src = (imageDisplayed.src == 'images/01.png') ? 'images/02.png' : 'images/01.png';
}
```